# Incremental Update the data of a Power BI table from Excel On Premise

Tags: excel, powershell, powerbi, append

I use this command to copy the excel file from On Premise to Sharepoint:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/NameSite" -ClientId "########################" -Thumbprint "##################################" -Tenant "domain.onmicrosoft.com"

$SourceFilePath = "C:\Users\Documents\Excel.xlsx"
$DestinationPath = "Shared Documents/FolderSite"
Add-PnPFile -Path $SourceFilePath -Folder $DestinationPath

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

I would like to avoid that the table is constantly scanned. I would like the new data to be integrated into the table without the table being completely redone at each update.

The idea is to incremente data. Knowing that my excel file comes from On Premise.

This method not works for incremental data in file :

```
#passthru stores object as type OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

$fileobj = Get-Process | Export-Excel -PassThru

#use method GetAsByteArray() on OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage object to get byte array, create memory stream using said byte array

$memoryStream = New-Object -TypeName 'System.IO.MemoryStream' -ArgumentList (,$fileobj.GetAsByteArray())

#pass memory stream to Stream parameter in Add-PnpFile

Add-PnPFile -Stream $memorystream -Folder 'Shared Documents/FolderSite' -FileName Excel.xlsx
```